# Catch key pressed ajax event without input fields

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf

In a partner management, when partner number or name is entered, the partner info and photo are shown and input text to introduce partner number or name is hidden.

Then I want to execute a method in my backing bean when ESC or ENTER key are pressed

I catch the keyup event with with following javascript in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
        debugger;
        if (arguments[0].key == 'Esc') {
            alert("YEAH");
           }
    });
</script>
```

How can i call my backing bean method???

```
public void listener() {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case(27):
       // switch boolean attribute in bean to render view hidden panel  
    }
}
```

I've tryed with remote command or ajax listener:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remote" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.listener}" update="input_table"/>


<f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this keyCode" listener="#{registerVisitBean.listener}" update="input_table" />
<h:inputHidden id="keyCode" binding="#{keyCode}" value="#{registerVisitBean.keyCode}" />
```

Both methods catch the keyup when input text is selected but when i hide it to show partner info, listener stop working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
        debugger;
        if (arguments[0].key == 'Esc') {
            alert("YEAH");
            // suppose you want to call your listener here
            remote([{name: 'key', value: arguments[0].key}]);
           }
    });
</script>

<p:remoteCommand name="remote" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.listener}" update="input_table"/>


public void listener() {
   Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
   String keyCode = params.get("key");

   // your code     
}
```

Comment: it works nice, now i have to figure out how to handle correctly enter and esc events! thanks!